# How do you print out repeated lines according to my problems below?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, ls, wc

Below are the questions that I'm having trouble with, I only know how to redirect the stdout of `ls` to the foobar file on question 1: `ls > foobar`

1. Write a command line to redirect stdout of the command `ls` to the `foobar` file and connect stdout to the stdin of the `wc` command. Do not use the respective file descriptors and complete the command in the order the instructions are given.
2. Write a command line to display in the shell only the lines that repeat.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: @waltinator I would be able to if only I know the way, if you know, please help me out.

Comment: It is not clear what context there is to these questions: what are you supposed to know at the point in your studies? "Write a command line" suggests you are intended to use existing commands, not script your own. You might try to find out what the `|` operator does in Bash (or any shell), and read the output from `man tee` and `man uniq`.

Comment: @Kudoss please do not confuse a problem assignment with a question ... `Write a command line ...` is not a question, it is a description of a problem that you are supposed to solve ... you need to think of a question that you would like to ask

Comment: #1 is beginner level - fair enough, but #2 as written is deceptively hard. Are you sure the question says what you've asked?

Comment: @roaima, I don't think 2 is that hard, after reading `man uniq`...

Comment: @TobySpeight "_`uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent_". Consider the lines `a`, `b`, `a`. The only line that repeats is `a`, so it should be the only line that's output. `uniq` doesn't do this

Comment: @roaima, I guess we had different interpretations of what "repeat" means in the problem statement, then!  Oh, for a clear specification....!  (Still, shouldn't be too hard to `sort` into `uniq`)

Answer (score 3):

This *looks* like a shell primer, so you *probably* expected to **know** some utilities that are common shell helpers (for example I see cited the `wc` utility).

If that is the case, then question #2 is simply asking you if you remember what the shell utility `uniq` does; because the answer is, *"pipe the output to uniq -d"*.

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\ntwo\nthree" # Echo four lines, one is repeated
one
two
two
three
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\ntwo\nthree" | uniq -d    # Filter the four
two
```

**UPDATE**: to output lines that repeat *even out of order*, you just need to sort those lines so that repeated lines are adjacent and can be recognized by `uniq -d`. You do this using `sort` before `uniq`: "... | sort | uniq -d".

"Connecting the stdout of A to the stdin of B" is done with the pipe character (similar to the > character you already know): `A | B`. This is what happens, above, when the stdout of `echo` is *piped* to the stdin of `uniq -d`.

All this said, you *should have been able* to answer those questions yourself. The fact that you weren't should tell you that you need to go back and review the lessons, notes, tutorial, or whatever came before those questions; if you missed the use of the pipe symbol, *who knows what else you might have missed?* - and that, actually, is the purpose of these silly questions: make you realize when you need to strenghten your foundations.

Comment: Re `uniq`, that's not what the question asks. As written it implies that given three lines `a`, `b`, `a`, the output should be only `a` because that's the only line that repeats

Comment: @roaima I read it differently, probably because English isn't my primary language. Updated answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

2/ a little shell script which print each line equal to the previous one :

```
( read a ; while read b ; do if [[ "$a" = "$b" ]] ; then echo "$a" ; fi ; a="$b";done ; )
```

You can type this line followed by `< a_file`

Most (all?) of the idioms are from the bash manual (`man bash`).

Comment: That's not what the question asks. As written it implies that the three lines `a`, `b`, `a` should only output `a` because that's the only line that repeats

Comment: We just have to insert a `sort |` before the program. But a more precise description of what is wanted should be better before trying to enhance the program. 
And if the purpose is a little bit complex, perl, python or whatever the language which support associative arrays will be used preferably instead of sh.

Comment: @roaima  (2) is so badly defined that your point is an open question, and given the apparent level of study I would expect `uniq` to be sufficient answer. Of course, there is an 8-character awk script for the more general case, admittedly subtle, but occurring thousands of times online.